# Initializing Slice of type Struct in Golang

Tags: pointers, go, struct, slice

I have the following structure in Golang

```
type mystruct struct {
        Name  string
        Power int
    }
```

My purpose is to write a function that takes as input a slice of type *mystuct and returns a slice of type int containing the "Power" property taken from the input slice.

my code is presented below:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    obj := make([]*mystruct, 15)
    for i, s := range obj {
        s.Power = i
    }
    fmt.Println(extractpowers(obj))
}
func extractpowers(obj []*mystruct) []int {
    powers := make([]int, len(obj))
    for i, s := range obj {
        powers[i] = s.Power
    }
    return powers

}
```

My issue is that the `obj := make([]*mystruct, 15)` creates a slices of 15 *mystruc pointers initialized to nil; which causes the code within the for loop to raise a panic of type "invalid memory or nil pointer dereference".

My question is what is the proper and fastest way to initialize the slice; (the equivalent of var lst = new List(Of mystruct) in .net)

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) and take its address in the loop:

```
for i := range obj {
    obj[i] = &mystruct{Power: i}
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/u-aGMA7TmUl).